# How to change Multiple dropdown with jquery json and php

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui

Hello Guys i want to change state based upon the country and the city according to state.

```
<label>Country:</label><br/>
        <select onchange="getval(this)">
        <option value="">Select Country</option>
        <option value="india">India</option>
        <option value="america">America</option>
        </select>


    <select name="" id="">
        <option value="">Select State</option>
        <option value="india">Orissa</option>
        <option value="india">Telangan</option>
        <option value="america">USA</option>
        <option value="america">California</option>
    </select>



<select name="" id="">
    <option value="">Select city</option>
    <option value="orissa">Nal</option>
    <option value="orissa">Mir</option>
    <option value="Telangan">Hyd</option>
    <option value="Telangan">Vija</option>
    <option value="america">KRK</option>
    <option value="america">MRK</option>
</select>


How to change state based on country. and afterthat change city based on state.
Thanks in advance.
```

Just i want look like this below link.
 http://demos.thesoftwareguy.in/multiple-dropdown-jquery-ajax-php/

Comment: Show your code, what you try so far?

Comment: you need to learn ajax for that.

Comment: @Nikhil Vaghla i did write any code. i Don't know how write code. It should change on based upon the first select option.

Comment: Please first of all try to  do code your self and then ask question.

Comment: @JBK: this is not a "do that for me". Learn it your self. There are good documentaries available for javascript

Comment: @Muhammad Nouman: why? Not essentially necessary.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is easy to make, you only have to play with Ajax and onChange event in yours dropdowns:

```
<select id="idCountries" onchange="updateStatesByCountry()">
    <option value="">Select Country</option>
    <option value="india">India</option>
    <option value="america">America</option>
</select>

<select id="idStates" onchange="updateCitiesByState()">
    <option value="">Select State</option>
    <option value="india">Orissa</option>
    <option value="india">Telangan</option>
    <option value="america">USA</option>
    <option value="america">California</option>
</select>

...
```

In your JS code add the needed functions:

```
function updateStatesByCountry(){
    console.log($('#idCountries').val());
    //Here add Ajax logic to load a new dropdown with all states of the current country

    //Your AJAX call should be something like this
    $.get('/getStatesByCountry?country='+ $('#idCountries option:selected').val(),    function(data){
        $('#idStates').empty();
        $('#idStates').append(data);
    });
});
}

//Same logic for the next dropdowns.
```

And I highly recommend you read about AJAX before you write this code.

Comment: Here i am not using ajax or any database table. Change using only javascript or jquery only to change on the first item.

Comment: @JBK but you need to retrieve the data to populate on each dropdown when the previous one is changed, you can use JS arrays with all default values for each country/state

Comment: Ok Thanks Your for suggestion and code. But can't use ajax here is there any other solution.

Comment: can we use array or json instead of ajax

Comment: @JBK yes you could use it, but would be static data, but you can